# How to configure an existing Magento 2.1.7 project in another PC and Database?

Tags: php, git, magento, magento2, magento2.1

I am new to Magento. 
I have a **working Magento 2.1.7** project. I want to put it in git repository?

If I put the working Magento directory into git and after cloning the repository to a local machine then **how do I install the existing project and do the database configuration?**

**I tried copy pasting the existing repository** to another machine and tried to install it by following the normal way of Magento installation but it didn't happen, instead **I got this error:**

```
An error has happened during application run. See exception log for details.
```

**I tried to import the database** as well but **I got this error** while importing:

```
Warning: Unknown: Input variables exceeded 1000. To increase the limit change max_input_vars in php.ini. in <b>Unknown</b> on line <b>0</b><br /> SET SQL_MODE ="NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO"
```

**I extended** `the max_input_vars` to **10000** from the **php.ini** file but **still the same error**.

Please suggest me about how can I configure and install an existing Magento 2.1.7 project **cuz I want to put the working project to GIT for my team to work with !.**

Comment: Did you restart httpd after the `.ini` change?

Comment: yes i did restart it but still the same error.

Comment: try to upload zip of sql file

Comment: no ! still the same. the file is getting imported successfully and executes some 8 queries and then it shows the error.                                              
<br /> <b>Warning</b>: Unknown: Input variables exceeded 1000. To increase the limit change max_input_vars in php.ini. in <b>Unknown</b> on line <b>0</b><br /> SET SQL_MODE = "NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO"

Answer (score 0):

These are the following steps see below:

**Step 1:** Backup the Magento MySQL Database -

you can take a backup via phpmyadmin or command base (mysqldump -h HOST -u USER -p DATABASENAME > FILENAME.sql)

**Step 2:** Transfer all Magento Files

**Step 3:** Adjust the Magento Configuration -

In Magento 2, you need to edit the app/etc/env.php file with new configurations according to your local server. See the url below

http://newsgento.com/migrate-magento-2-from-one-server-to-another/

**Step 4:** goto core_config_data table change base url / secure url into database to your local server url.